# CSS table-cell content not on top

Tags: html, css

I created a row which has the css rule display set to table.
The elements inside this row are having display: `table-cell`.

The problem now is, if I'm trying to add new elements to the cells the content of each cell aren't on top of the cell.

This is how I solved the above in CSS in code format:

```
.field-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.field-row .field-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
.content-field {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is, that I have all columns at the same height and the content should be on top of each column.

> jsfiddle of my code:

```css
.field-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.field-row .field-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}

.content-field {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-row">
  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
    <div class="content-field profile">
      <div class="content-field">
        <img id="img" src="" height="150px" width="150px">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
    <div class="content-field">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
    <div class="content-field">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hopefully I can get a solution for this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A suggestion, perhaps instead of using the archaic `table`  layout you should consider scratching your current code and using the new (and imho better) [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Will take a hour to learn, but will end up saving you a lot of time in the long run

Comment: Another step-up from flexbox would be to use the new `grid` layout that can be used as well as a `table` for display elements in a grid-like layout.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly I think all you need to do is add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.field-row .field-wrapper` style.

```css
.field-row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.field-row .field-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top; /* add this here */
}

.content-field {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field-row">
  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
    <div class="content-field profile">
      <div class="content-field">
        <img id="img" src="" height="150px" width="150px">
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
    <div class="content-field">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field-wrapper" style="background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);">
    <div class="content-field">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="content-field">
      <p>Hello World!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```